# Jquery.submit() - Changing Form Values before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript that submits to an HTML form in my app upon a "click" event like so....

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  $('form').submit()
});
```

However I want to change the data before I send it. Is this possible? I don't want to use Ajax $.post if I can help it. I just want to change what the form sends to my Rails controller before submit.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just update the field values before calling ".submit()".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have a field with name="search" you can change it's value like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

   $('form input[name="search"]').val( place.name );
  $('form').submit()
});
```

Or if not:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="search" value="'+place.name+'" />').submit()
});
```

Assuming `place.name` is known like in your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the value of specific fields by id before you call submit:

```
$("form #fieldID").val("Value you want to change");
```